# Position <div> near <map> <area>

Tags: html, css

I have HTML `<map>` tag with let's say 3 area's. On click event on area 1,2 or 3 I want to display a `<div class="pop-content">`  with different content for each `<area>`.

At the moment my `<div class="pop-content">` is floating to the top like on this picture.

[image]

What I want is to display my `<div class="pop-content">` next to each `<area>` like on this image.

[image]

So far my CSS

```
.pop-content{
  width: 100px;
  height : 120px;
  background-color: gray;
  position: relative;
}
```

Question is how to CSS `<div class="pop-content">` to achieve positions like on 2 image?

I striped my example from my project and reproduced it in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PawelK/Lh4fwkyv/)

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: Hey, I added JSFIDDLE to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

[**JSFIddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh4fwkyv/1/)

**Solution:**

```
img {
    position: absolute;
}

.pop-content {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 69px;
  left: 101px;
}
```

**NOTE:** But for each planet(`<area>`) introduce new class like `pop-content1`, `pop-content2` and so on that has different positions.